# Generate Random Move: Dots and Boxes Game: MIPS

Tags: random, printing, mips

I am trying to write a two player Dots and Boxes game. I am facing difficulty in generating random number for Computer and printing the same on the board.
Any assistance would be helpful.
The code for the user is working just fine but not the computer move.

```
computerMove:
    li $a0, 0           # Set $a to int 0
    li $a1, 99          # Set upperbound to 99
    li $v0, 42          # Call Random Int Range
    syscall
    add $a0, $a0, 48        # add 48, since 0 starts at 48

    li $v0, 1           # Printing $a0 to verify -- Generates wrong number
    syscall

    li $s0, 50          # Flag
    li $s1, 97          # Setting $s1 to 'a'
    beq $a0, 97, placePiece     # if $a0 is 'a' then placePience

    li $s1, 98          # Setting $s1 to 'b'
    beq $a0, 98, placePiece     # if $a0 is 'b' then placePiece

    move $s1, $a0           # moving $a0 to $s1 for placePiece
    bgt $a0, 57 computerMove    # if $a0 greater 57 then continue
    j placePiece            # else placePiece

placePiece:
    move $t0, $s1
    # Placing Values    
    lb $t1, addr($t0)
    lb $t2, mark($t0)
    sb $t2, board($t1)
    j printBoard

printBoard:
    la $a0, board
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    beq $s0, 50, continue
    j computerMove


.data

board:      .ascii   "\n\n   . . .          . 0 . 1 ."
            .ascii     "\n                  2   3   4"
            .ascii     "\n   . . .          . 5 . 6 ."
            .ascii     "\n                  7   8   9"
            .asciiz    "\n   . . .          . a . b .\n"

addr:       .byte       6,   8,  33,  35,  37,  62,  64,  89,  91,  93,  118, 120
mark:       .byte       '-', '-', '|', '|', '|', '-', '-', '|', '|', '|', '-', '-'
box:        .byte       34,  36,  90,  92
```

Comment: _"Generates wrong number"_ <-- What does that mean exactly? What did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: You are setting the upper bound of the random number to 99. You probably want to use 9.

Comment: @Michael After the random number is generated, I am comparing to the ASCII values for 0-9 (48-57) || a-b (97-98), if matches I print them on the board. The problem is, it is not print on the board correctly.

Comment: @markgz I cannot use 9, since I am comparing ASCII values.